# Laravel Property [title] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting an error while trying to display data from the database.This problem occurred by other people who have created posts on this website. but they have a foreach loop and I don't. so all the answers given for this problem do not work.

**article controller**

```
public function showwereld($id)
{
    $artikels = Artikel::where('id', $id);
    return view('pages.show')->with('artikels', $artikels);
}
```

**show.blade.php**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="artikeltitel marginauto">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h2>{{$artikels->title}}</h2>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">{{$artikels->intro}}</p>              
            <p>{{$artikels->body}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The error is showing that $artikels is a Builder instance, which doesn't seem to correlate with your code sample.  Your code sample would have $artikels as a Collection instance, which also wouldn't have a  title property, but indicates that you're either posting the wrong code or looking at the wrong code.

Comment: thanks i am going to look into that right now

Comment: Artikel::where('id', $id)->get(); Otherwise you get a query builder. Edit: that's still a colelction so you should actually do : Artikel::where('id', $id)->first();

Comment: Do you have the title field in Artikel? what does {{dd($artikels)}} give you if you add this in the blade?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

this on controller

```
public function index()
{
    $artikel =  Artikel::where('category_id', '1')->first();
    return view('pages.wereld',compact('artikel'));
}
```

in view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="artikeltitel marginauto">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <h2>{{$artikel->title}}</h2>
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">{{$artikel->intro}}</p>              
            <p>{{$artikel->body}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this atoui, but when i add this piece of code it still gives me the same error

Comment: did you want to show single or collection of articles ?

Comment: only one single row out of my database but the only results on this problem are with foreachloops

Comment: good , replace get method with first method in this line : Artikel::where('category_id', '1')->get() become Artikel::where('category_id', '1')->first();

Comment: it gives me this error: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: i see , let's try to replace : return view('pages.wereld')->with('artikels', $artikels) become : return view('pages.wereld',compact('artikels'))

Comment: still the same error Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: i think the article with id=1 not found , put this code :dd($artikels) befoe retrun view  to see if there is record

Comment: check my post, i edited a screenshot in where i've got the object from DD

Comment: i edited my answer and provide the full code ,can you try it (copy and past)

Answer (score 13):

I think you are missing the `get()` :
`$artikels = Artikel::where('id', $id)->get();`

Comment: In my case it was ->first()

Answer (score 2):

**Eager Loading Relationships(THIS WILL WORK JUST UNDERSTAND THIS)**

DataTables support searching and sorting of eager loaded relationships when using Eloquent. this example will show you how to setup a eager loading search using Eloquent Engine.

To enable search, we need to eager load the relationship we intend to use using Laravel's ***User::with('posts')*** api.

```
use DataTables;

Route::get('user-data', function() {
$model = App\User::with('posts');

return DataTables::eloquent($model)
            ->addColumn('posts', function (User $user) {
                return $user->posts->map(function($post) {
                    return str_limit($post->title, 30, '...');
                })->implode('<br>');
            })
            ->toJson();
});
```

To trigger search on ***posts*** relationship, we need to specify the ***relation.column_name*** as the ***name*** attribute in our ***javascript*** appropriately.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ url("collection/basic-object-data") }}',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
            {data: 'posts', name: 'posts.title'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'}
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Looking at ***{data: 'posts', name: 'posts.title'},***:

***data: posts*** represents the data key ***(data.posts)*** that we are going to display on our table.
***name: posts.title*** represents the User model relationship (***posts***) and the column we are going to perform our search (***title***).

Answer (score 0):

Or basically try this:

```
$artikel = Artikel::find($id);
return view(pages.wereld, ['artikel' => $artikel]);
```

on view use this:

```
    {{ $artikel->name }}
```

On your code: You are calling to get a record but trying to use the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not added in the hidden properties inside your model? if not then

```
$artikels = Artikel::where('id', $id)->get();
```

OR

```
$artikels = Artikel::where('id', $id)->first();
```

should work